# angularjs test if file exists for ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-include to bring in a partial in an AngularJS app.  If the partial .html file doesn't exist, I would like to do something else.

The partial name is extracted from the $location.path().  So if the path is "/foo", then I would like use "my_partial_foo.html".  However if "my_partial_foo.html" doesn't exist, then I'd like to use "my_partial_default.html" instead.

I'm putting this data into a $dialog, so I can't use the typical routeProvider functionality (afaik).

My main question is:  How do I determine if "my_partial_foo.html" exists before I use it in an ng-include directive?

Related questions:

[angular - reusable dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048392/angular-reusable-dialogs)

[How to prepopulate a dialog in angularjs/bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054741/how-to-prepopulate-a-dialog-in-angularjs-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work.  Basically the $templateCache will always have a key for my_partial_foo.html (so your ng-include can always reference it) but the value might be the default or the real thing.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []).run(function($templateCache,$http){
  $http.get('my_partial_foo.html',
    //success
    function(data){
      $templateCache.put('my_partial_foo.html', data);
    },
    //failure
    function(){
      $http.get('my_partial_default.html', function(data){
        $templateCache.put('my_partial_foo.html', data);
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  So far I have been not using the $http module.  Is there a way to do this with just ng-include?  Maybe I can monkey-patch it?

Comment: BTW, still new to AngularJS, so what you've said might be the AngularJS way?

Comment: ng-include essentially does the same thing in its current state.  why don't you want to use $http?

Comment: no real reason, just less to worry about.  I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need but found the built-in `$templateCache` & ui.router's `$templateFactory` to have inconsistent behavior.  When I'd use this...

```
$templateFactory.fromUrl( './non-existant.html' )
.catch( function( err ){ console.log( 'does not exist' )})
```

...it would fail to trigger the catch callback.  It was only after hitting this call twice would the error get triggered.

So I rolled my own solution using `$q` and `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
.service( 'templateUtils', [
    '$q'
    function( $q ){
        var api = {
             hasTemplate: function( url ){
                  var d = $q.defer()
                  var rqst = new XMLHttpRequest()
                  rqst.open( 'GET', url )
                  rqst.onload = function( evt ){
                       if( evt.target.status === 200 )
                           d.resolve( true )
                       else
                           d.reject( false )
                  } 

                  return d.promise
             }
        }

        return api
    }
])
```

I use this like so...

```
var templateUrl = './default-template.html'

templateUtils.hasTemplate( urlToCheck )
.then( function( rsp ){ templateUrl = './different-template.html' })
```